# Android HTTPPOST issues with error handling and pausing

Tags: php, android

I am very very very new to writing apps for Android, so I hope this isn't seen as a waste of time to others. I am also pretty sure my code isn't very well put together, so try not to laugh.

I'm trying to send values from my app to a remote PHP form. While what I have seems to work just fine in sending the information to the form, I can't figure out how I'm supposed to handle an error if the app has no connectivity to the internet and I can't send anything, so I'm not sure how to make it display a toast or error message to inform the user that the message was never sent and why.

I'm also unsure how to pause everything for about 3-4 seconds when either a sent confirmation or an error is displayed. I've spent the last 4 hours struggling with these things, and browsing around stackoverflow and a few other forums to try and find some code examples to give me that "AH HA!" moment, but no such luck.

I hope someone can help me out or point out whatever I'm doing wrong with this. Thanks!

My entire code is as follows:

```
package net.testapp.commenter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class suptest extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private EditText name, email, phone, comment;
private Button postbutton;
private ProgressBar pbfirst;
private RelativeLayout pbdark, pbsent;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.suptest);

    // stuff in the layout
    name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    phone=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    comment=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    postbutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
    pbfirst=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    pbdark=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.pbdark);
    pbsent=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.pbsent);

    // hide some stuff up front
    pbfirst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    pbdark.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    pbsent.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    // post button listener thingy
    postbutton.setOnClickListener(this);

// Go back button
Button goback = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goback);
goback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
});
};

// clicking the send button
public void onClick(View v) {
        if(email.getText().toString().length()<1){
        // TODO LEARN HOW TO APPLY THIS TO OTHER FIELDS AS WELL

        // Remind user to fill in text fields
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill in all fields.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }else{
            //show my progress bar and dark fullscreen layout for "Sending" text to overlay
            pbdark.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pbfirst.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            new MyAsyncTask().execute();        
        }
} 

// Where all the http post magic happens
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{

    @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        postData(); 
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Double result){

        //make progress bar and dark background for "Sending" test vanish
        pbfirst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pbdark.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        //make sent confirmation appear
        pbsent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // TODO FIGURE OUT HOW TO PAUSE ON SENT CONFIRMATION MESSAGE JUST LONG ENOUGH TO READ IT BEFORE FINISH()
        finish();

    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
        pbfirst.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    public void postData() {

        // Strings for the layout stuff
        String  namer = name.getText().toString();
        String  emailer = email.getText().toString();
        String  phoner = phone.getText().toString();
        String  commenter = comment.getText().toString();

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.mysite.net/commentform.php");

        try {

            // talk to the PHP script
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", namer));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", emailer));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("number", phoner));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("comments", commenter));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // execute the http post
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }

}

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "pause everything for 3-4 seconds?"

Comment: Well, whenever the information is being sent, I make a layout visible which covers the entire screen and darkens it, and above that I display a progressbar spinner and textview that reads "Sending Comment" (pbdark & pbfirst). Then after everything sends properly, I wanted to display another layout (pbsent) where it shows the comment has been sent. But when I put something like wait(3000); just after making pbsent visible, and then after the wait, a finish(); to send everything back to the main menu, I end up with the pause, but it seems to happen before the pbsent layout is displayed

Comment: Ok, I don't completely understand what you're saying there, but I think what you're trying to do is make an android view or fragment of some kind disappear a certain number of seconds after the comment is successfully sent?  My thought process would be to create a new Thread and run a Runnable on that thread which 1. calls Thread.sleep(3000), and 2. then calls whatever code you have which closes the view.  You have to be careful that you don't lock up the ui thread, etc... etc...

Comment: actually I want it to appear over the activity for a few seconds to be read, before vanishing. The part where I set pbsent to VISIBLE is what I'd like to pause on the screen for two or three seconds, before it gets to finish();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I think I managed to figure out why it was crashing. Apparently the AsyncTask being a different thread is unable to manipulate the UI stuff, so I had to put this in my catches to display error messages and so on...

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    //And now for my one line of code to display the error message
     pber2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     }
});
```

I hope this at least helps someone else in the future!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by adding code within your catch blocks for ClientProtocolException and IOException, no?  Use some code like the below to show a dialog, or you could just use android toasts...

```
    public void showDialog(final Activity activity, final String title, final String message) {

    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // 1. Instantiate an AlertDialog.Builder with its constructor
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);

            // 2. Chain together various setter methods to set the dialog
            // characteristics
            builder.setMessage(message).setTitle(title);

            // 3. Get the AlertDialog from create()
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

            dialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm going to have to look this over. As I mentioned before, I'm a complete novice with coding and I don't have the experience and understanding in some cases to add new code to what I have without problems. So far I can't seem to make it fit.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm doing this correctly. I've even tried putting toasts in the catch blocks you mentioned, but the app just crashes out each time I try to send the comment in airplane mode or with 3G/4G and Wifi disabled. I'm not sure how to tell the app not to crash and instead display something for the user so they're aware of the connectivity situation.

Comment: Ok, sorry I didn't realize it was crashing on you, I was thinking along the lines that the catch blocks already there were just silently swallowing the exception thrown because of the connectivity problem.  Have you tried looking in your ADB logs, seeing what exception is being thrown and where, and then adding an exception handler for that?

Comment: I can never really get much information from the crash. Right now I just have layouts that go from GONE to VISIBLE whenever.